Xserver crashes after system update shows blank screen
I updated my Elemetary Os 6.1 with apt-get update and upgrade after rebooting, shows GRUB menu but was completely blank, no login screen. Tried using previous kernel but same issue. However in recovery mode could get login screen but as soon as I enter password it would loop back to login screen again.
Currently I am able to access tty1 by Ctrl + Alt + F1
inxi -Fxxxz,
The update history which caused this issue,
journalctl -b
Xorg.0.log
dmesg | grep amdgpu
I read various issues similar to this but had no solutions or weren't exactly the same 
Please help me
